# WPF custom key for access key

Tags: wpf, xaml

Currently in my application, I am utilizing `AccessText` within a `Button` to register keyboard shortcuts. Currently I am setting the shortcut using the first letter of a resource string. One particular issue with this approach is changes to language (via localization) may register multiple buttons with the same letter.

An current example:

```
<AccessText x:Uid="AccessText_4" 
            Text="{Binding Source={x:Static resx:Resources.ServerManagement_SettingsButton}, StringFormat='_{0}'}" />
```

Again, the first letter from the resource string will become the `AccessKey` (which is designated as the letter which follows the first underline). If the language is changed, I can't granted that some of the access keys will not be duplicate.

Is there any way to set a permanent `AccessKey` on `AccessText`?

Comment: You likely can't be sure the predetermined access key will even appear in the localized text for every language.  You may need to include the access keys in the localized resources themselves, trying your best to avoid collisions.  You'll probably miss some (I've seen collisions in Visual Studio before), but you can fix them as they're reported.  Another option would be to whip up a custom solution using `AccessKeyManager`, but you'd have to come up with a custom way of indicating what an element's access key actually is.  Maybe an overlay like the Office Ribbon?

Answer (score 0):

One way might be to perform this in the code behind using the [`AccessKeyManager.Register`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.accesskeymanager.register(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Duplicate as necessary for each button.
    AccessKeyManager.Register("s", btnSearch);
}
```

You would remove the underline from your Xaml (no StringFormat). As the [`AccessKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.accesstext.accesskey(v=vs.110).aspx) is a read-only property, I do not see a way to set this in Xaml.

I haven't tested this myself but hopefully it points you in the right direction.